# WPF: How to change the Map Point coordinate(lat/long) to screen point (x-y) on ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, land-survey, wpf

My project required me to perform a close traverse to plotting by placing a marker on that particular point. My problem now is that the traverse calculation are in x-y plane, but to plot a point using marker on ArcGIS require Lat/long. So my idea just know to get the current x-y point of current coordinate point then calculate, but how can i change from x-y point to map coordinate?

Comment: I don't see many questions on this forum about WPF, so is there another forum perhaps?  I am familiar with traverses and surveying, and I thought you would have a good starting coordinate from a GPS or field surveying device?

Comment: @danak yes i get the starting coordinate from the marker i plot on map. The issue now that screen point coordinate always change when the user rendered the map. The map coordinate are fixed, so after i make a calculation for close traverse i need it to add to the marker current screen point coordinate(x-y) to plot the close traverse point by change it to map coordinate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i keep searching i find a way that convert the map coordinate to screen point coordinate by using this:

```
double longitude = 100.458802; //reference starting point
double latitude = 5.997545;
location = new MapPoint(longitude,latitude, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
screenPoint = mapView.LocationToScreen(location);
```

I though this method of mine can plot the marker correctly but it seem other thing need to consider first.